# How to get Kivy accordion to collapse on press and how to set default accordion collapse setting

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy

we're using an accordion in the home menu of our Kivy app and are struggling with two problems:

1) When we open an accordion item, the item won't collapse when we press on the item a second time. The only way to get it to collapse is to press on another accordion item. Is this simply the way Kivy's accordion widget works or is there a way to alter this setting?

2) When our screen opens, the last accordion item in the list appears as expanded from the get go. How do we get this accordion item to load in a collapsed position? We tried setting collapse: True in our kv file but this did not work

Our kv code is as follows:

```
GeneralBoxLayout:
    GridLayout1:
    BodyBoxLayout:
        rows: 2
        GeneralTextGridLayout:
            size_hint: (1,.07)
            GeneralTextLabel:
                text: '[color=0046C3]Select a topic[/color]'
        ScrollView:
            size_hint: (1,.93)
            HomeGridLayout:
                Accordion:
                    orientation: "vertical"
                    AccordionItem:
                        title: "Topic 1"
                        background_normal: 'img/blue_button5.png'
                        background_selected: 'img/blue_button5.png'
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height: '50dp'
                        font_size: '12sp'
                        border: 20, 20, 20, 20
                        GameButton0:
                            text: 'Game 1'

                    AccordionItem:
                        title: 'Topic 2'
                        background_normal: 'img/blue_button5.png'
                        background_selected: 'img/blue_button5.png'
                        GameButton0:
                            text: 'Game 1'

                    AccordionItem:
                        title: 'Topic 3'
                        background_normal: 'img/blue_button5.png'
                        background_selected: 'img/blue_button5.png'
                        GameButton0:
                            text: 'Game 1'

                    AccordionItem:
                        title: 'Topic 4'
                        background_normal: 'img/blue_button5.png'
                        background_selected: 'img/blue_button5.png'
                        GameButton0:
                            text: 'Game 1'

                    AccordionItem:
                        title: 'Topic 5'
                        background_normal: 'img/blue_button5.png'
                        background_selected: 'img/blue_button5.png'
                        GameButton0:
                            text: 'Game 1'

                    AccordionItem:
                        title: 'Topic 6'
                        background_normal: 'img/blue_button5.png'
                        background_selected: 'img/blue_button5.png'
                        GameButton0:
                            text: 'Game 1'

                    AccordionItem:
                        title: 'Topic 7'
                        background_normal: 'img/blue_button5.png'
                        background_selected: 'img/blue_button5.png'
                        GameButton0:
                            text: 'Game 1'

                    AccordionItem:
                        title: 'Topic 8'
                        background_normal: 'img/blue_button5.png'
                        background_selected: 'img/blue_button5.png'
                        GameButton0:
                            text: 'Game 1'

                    AccordionItem:
                        title: 'Topic 9'
                        background_normal: 'img/blue_button5.png'
                        background_selected: 'img/blue_button5.png'
                        collapse: True
                        GameButton0:
                            text: ' Game 1'

    FooterGridLayout:
        ReturnButton:
            text: 'Logout'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to fix your first problem, but what I did to make the accordion start in the expanded position was to use a collapse: False flag to my first accordion item.

```
MyAccordion:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        MyItem:           #The the top accordion item that needs to open expanded
            title: 'First Item'
            collapse: False

        MyItem:           #The the next accordion item, will be collapsed
            title: 'Second Item'

        MyItem:           #The the next accordion item, will also be collapsed
            title: 'Third Item'
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I realize this question is 5 years old but I just ran into this myself today and was able to get it working (at least for what I'm doing) by creating custom `Accordion` and `AccordionItem` classes, and overwriting `Accordion._do_layout` and `AccordionItem.on_touch_down`.  I just copied and pasted these methods from their base class and made a few small changes noted below.

```
# file: popupaccordion.py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.accordion import Accordion, AccordionItem
from kivy.logger import Logger

class PopUpAccordion(Accordion):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def _do_layout(self, dt):
        children = self.children
        if children:
            all_collapsed = all(x.collapse for x in children)
        else:
            all_collapsed = False

        # Changed below: if all items are collapsed, do nothing. This is what we want.
        # if all_collapsed:
        #     children[0].collapse = False

        orientation = self.orientation
        min_space = self.min_space
        min_space_total = len(children) * self.min_space
        w, h = self.size
        x, y = self.pos
        if orientation == 'horizontal':
            display_space = self.width - min_space_total
        else:
            display_space = self.height - min_space_total

        if display_space <= 0:
            Logger.warning('Accordion: not enough space '
                           'for displaying all children')
            Logger.warning('Accordion: need %dpx, got %dpx' % (
                min_space_total, min_space_total + display_space))
            Logger.warning('Accordion: layout aborted.')
            return

        if orientation == 'horizontal':
            children = reversed(children)

        for child in children:
            child_space = min_space
            child_space += display_space * (1 - child.collapse_alpha)
            child._min_space = min_space
            child.x = x
            child.y = y
            child.orientation = self.orientation
            if orientation == 'horizontal':
                child.content_size = display_space, h
                child.width = child_space
                child.height = h
                x += child_space
            else:
                child.content_size = w, display_space
                child.width = w
                child.height = child_space
                y += child_space

class PopUpAccordionItem(AccordionItem):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.title_template = 'PopUpAccordionItemTitle'

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if not self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            return
        if self.disabled:
            return True
        if self.collapse:
            self.collapse = False
            return True
        # Changed below: if item is not collapsed and user clicked the title bar, collapse.
        if not self.collapse and self.container_title.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            self.collapse = True
        return super(AccordionItem, self).on_touch_down(touch)

class PopUpAccordionApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return PopUpAccordion()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    PopUpAccordionApp().run()
```

```
# file: popupaccordion.kv

[PopUpAccordionItemTitle@Label]:
    text: ctx.title
    normal_background: ctx.item.background_normal if ctx.item.collapse else ctx.item.background_selected
    disabled_background: ctx.item.background_disabled_normal if ctx.item.collapse else ctx.item.background_disabled_selected
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: self.disabled_color if self.disabled else self.color
        BorderImage:
            source: self.disabled_background if self.disabled else self.normal_background
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
        PushMatrix
        Translate:
            xy: self.center_x, self.center_y
        Rotate:
            angle: 90 if ctx.item.orientation == 'horizontal' else 0
            axis: 0, 0, 1
        Translate:
            xy: -self.center_x, -self.center_y
    canvas.after:
        PopMatrix

<PopUpAccordion>:
    pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "y": 0}
    orientation: "vertical"
    PopUpAccordionItem:
        title: "test1"
        Label:
            text: "test item 1"
    PopUpAccordionItem:
        title: "test2"
        Label:
            text: "test item 2"
```

Note that the kv file contains a kivy template.  I'm not sure how these work, and kivy templates are deprecated.  But if you want to change the appearance of the buttons that open/close the `PopUpAccordionItem`'s, this is (at least one way) how you can do it.  Also note we connect the `PopUpAccordionItem` to its template in the `__init__` by passing it a string value of the template name... which seems strange but works.